# Google Map in User control not working for multtiple instances

Tags: javascript, controls

I have created user control which contains google map .
code in user control is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var map;
function intialize(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        //set the default center
       map.setCenter(myLatlng);
        //set the default zoom
       map.setZoom(initialZoom);

        //Set the map type
       map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
}
</script>

HTML code:
<div id="map_canvas" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 300px; border: solid 1px black;" > </div>
```

Call to Initialize() function is from code behind(.ascx.cs) using
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "FunctionCall", "initialize();")

Everythings works fine when single instance for user control is used in parent page (.aspx page).
But when I  tried to used this  user control multiple times in page ,only map for 1st instance is showing. But for other instances it is not showing anything but blank

I want to display Google maps for all instances of the user control 
For ex when user control is used 4 times,4 maps should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is generating a unique ID for each div element.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript will only add the map to the first "map_canvas" div. You might need to use jquery and change the div ids for this to work.